# Automatically Escape Quotes in SSIS Export

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I am using SQL Server 2014 with SSIS

I have a data set like this:

```
ID   Name              Status
1    Awesome "Store"   Active
2    Market, Place     Active
3    Vendor            Active
```

In SSMS, when the results are in the grid and I right click and choose save results as CSV, the raw output is this:

```
ID,Name,Status
1,"Awesome ""Store""",Active
2,"Market, Place",Active
3,Vendor,Active
```

I need to use SSIS to export the data from the database to a CSV file so that the raw output is exactly the same as above. I do not want to do any derived columns to replace strings or anything that would be a custom solution for each time I need to do this for a new data set.

I've tried using the flat file destination and setting the text qualifier to `"` but it puts quotes around every value (not a huge deal) but it does not escape the existing quotes in `Awesome "Store"` to `Awesome ""Store""` which is the main issue I am faced with.

Does anyone have a solution that will achieve what I am looking for? Thanks!

Comment: Putting quotes around every value is precisely what "text qualify" means. What you ask is how to *escape* existing double quotes inside the field values

Comment: A quick & dirty solution is to add a Derived Column transform before the Destination and replace the `"` character with `""`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but I specifically said that I do not want to do derived columns

Comment: Then you may be out of luck. CSV is a looselly defined "format". The `Flat File Destination` is meant to quickly export text, not create CSV that can cover all conventions like quoting text qualifiers or allowing field/line separators inside a field. You may have to install a third-party destination or use a script destination.

Comment: Use a delimiter other than comma like pipe (|) that's not in the source data.

Comment: What is your data source configured as?

Comment: Derived Column Transformation is the only way I've found. Try the solution from HomeCookN using REPLACE(column_name,"\"","\"\"") https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2e01d572-780e-4de4-b727-ca482ce788b8/how-to-have-ssis-escape-double-quotes-within-a-string-in-a-csv-file-destination-which-also-uses?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

## Editing TextQualified property

One thing to try, in the Flat File Connection manager, setthe Text Qualifier to `"` and go to the Advanced Tab, and for the first and Last Column change the `TextQualified` property to `False`. *[Read more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms183343(v=sql.110).aspx)*

[image]

If this is not working, i don't think there is a direct way to achieve this, without derived columns or other transformations. So the best workaround you can do is to change the Column Delimiter in the destination flat file to Tab (or anything different than comma `,`)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really use any other type of delimiter because the data that I am dealing with has pretty much every possible character, including tabs, in a field somewhere.

Comment: @MikeDeluca have you tried my first suggestion to change the TextQualified property for `ID` and `Status` Columns to `False` and leave it `True` to `Name` column

Comment: Yes, that didn't affect anything.

Comment: @MikeDeluca then i don't think there is a direct way to achieve this, without derived columns or other transformations. because you can choose to add text qualifiers to all columns or for none of them.

Comment: @MikeDeluca hope that you will get a better answer even if i think that you will not get a working one.

Comment: @MikeDeluca the first suggestion in this answer is working 100%. Just Select the TextQualifier = `"` in the Flat File Connection manager, after that go to the Advanced Tab, Change the TextQUalified property to `False` for all columns except the `Name` column. I try it and it is working fine using VS 2013

Comment: @Yahfoufi A text qualifier puts quotes around the entire field, it does not escape quotes within the field. So the result may end up being `"Awesome "Store""` but that is incorrect because it needs to be `"Awesome ""Store"""`

Comment: @MikeDeluca i don't think  you can achieve this without a derived column or a script component. This is the best that you can do without transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You specified you do not want to use derived columns,

does the following statement work in a SQL command SELECT?

```
CAST(REPLACE([column_name],'"','""')
```

otherwise you could create a SQL view in source or staging and put it there instead.
In that scenario you still need to change the SSIS package to look at the view instead.